# Download files with Python - "unknown url type"

Tags: python-3.x, file, web, rtf

I need to download a list of RTF files locally with Python3.

I tried with `urllib`

```
import urllib
url = "www.calhr.ca.gov/Documents/wfp-recruitment-flyer-bachelor-degree-jobs.rtf"
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

but I get a ValueError

```
ValueError: unknown url type: 'www.calhr.ca.gov/Documents/wfp-recruitment-flyer-bachelor-degree-jobs.rtf'
```

How to deal with this kind of file format?

Comment: You need `http://` in front to indicate the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `http://` in front of the url,

```
import urllib
url = "http://www.calhr.ca.gov/Documents/wfp-recruitment-flyer-bachelor-degree-jobs.rtf"
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```